# Possible to develop VSCode extensions on vscode.dev?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code-server

I'm currently using VSCode via https://github.com/coder/code-server and was reading https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

Has anyone succeeded in developing (and in the process, debug) a VSCode extension using code-server or https://vscode.dev?

Would like to know the steps on how it was setup.